# Using Parse.com as a middleman to provide user registration, etc. for my XMPP IM server

Tags: android, parse-platform, xmpp

I've just started off with [Parse.com](http://parse.com) and I'm loving the simplicity and effectiveness of the service so far.

My app will have an instant messaging feature for which, I realize, Parse is not suitable. I would still love to use Parse for user registration, easy Facebook and Google integration, and all the good things that come with it, but I also need to provide IM in my app.

I want to host my own XMPP server and somehow integrate this server with Parse.

My question is whether it will be possible to verify and create XMPP chat sessions between my users through Parse which will act as a middleman that provides username and password for authentication and to notify offline users through push notification, etc.

As I mentioned above, I would like to host my own XMPP server and would like to avoid services like Pusher.

However, I would like to know if there are any self hosted alternatives that have all the features of Parse as well as IM capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Parse.com as a mobile application server. I ended up moving to Amazon EC2 server on march this year. Because my users couldn't login Parse.com. This situation happens 1,2 or 3 times every week. Customers of Parse.com share servers which runs on Amazon Cloud Server.

If you think your app will be able to attract a lot of users, I think you better start with Amazon EC2. My server which runs on AWS has never gone down since I moved to this.

Although Parse.com provide simple and easy APIs which decrease repetitive work load for mobile applications, It is worth for you to implement them on your own. I think that can save your time eventually based on my experience.